# Rails & Wordpress Single Sign On - Authenticate using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress

I have a rails app serving the main site and a wordpress install serving a blog, which sits in a sub directory on the same domain. I am using devise for authentication in the rails app. I want to be able to know if a user is logged in when using the wordpress side of the site and get their user ID.

I have looked into SSO using doorkeeper, but am requiring some guidance.

Does anyone have any idea of how I can do this?